# Load xml item in radiobutton

Tags: jquery, xml, radio-button

I have this:

```
<fieldset>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="resp1" value=""></input>
    </label><br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="resp2" value=""></input>
    </label><br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="resp3" value=""></input>
    </label><br>
</fieldset>
```

And I want load in the radiobuttons xml's items, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RecentPreguntas>
 <Pregunta>
  <Title>Capital de Francia</Title>
  <Respuestas value="test">
   <Cierto value="test1">París</Cierto>
   <Falso value="test2">Berlín</Falso>
   <Falso value="test3">Roma</Falso>      
  </Respuestas>
 </Pregunta>
<Pregunta>
<Title>Capital de España</Title>
<Respuestas>
  <Falso>Berlín</Falso>
  <Falso>Lisboa</Falso>
  <Cierto>Madrid</Cierto>
</Respuestas>
</Pregunta>
<Pregunta>
<Title>Capital de Rumanía</Title>
<Respuestas>
  <Falso>Budapest</Falso>
  <Falso>Berlín</Falso>
  <Cierto>Bucarest</Cierto>      
</Respuestas>
</Pregunta>
<Pregunta>
<Title>Capital de Bélgica</Title>
<Respuestas>
  <Cierto>Bruselas</Cierto>
  <Falso>Estocolmo</Falso>
  <Falso>Oslo</Falso>
</Respuestas>
```

The javascript

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
    var $items = $(xml).find("Pregunta");
    var itemsCount = $items.length;
    $("#pregunta").each(function(){
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*itemsCount);
        $(this).append($($items.get(random)).find("Title"));                            
    });   
}
```

With this i get the questions, now i dont know how to do the answers.

Comment: Could you expand some more on what it is you want to do, I don't really understand. Where do the xml file come from? What's your starting state and your end state? Is the xml file generated from the radio buttons or do you want to populate the radiobuttons with values from an xml file?

Comment: Sorry, I want to populate the radiobuttons with values from an xml file. I have xml file and I get pass the questions but no the answers. Maybe the different title (Cierto/Falso) is the problem?

Comment: You said you tried with jQuery? Could you post that jQuery code or any other code you've tried with?

Comment: Sorry, I'll have to come back to this on Monday Hope someone else can help you until then though.

Comment: now I get the answers with this:

        <Respuesta id="1">París</Respuesta>
  <Respuesta id="2">Berlín</Respuesta>
       <Respuesta id="3">Roma</Respuesta>

And this:

$("#p1").append($($items.get(random)).find("Respuesta#1"));   $("#p2").append($($items.get(random)).find("Respuesta#2"));   $("#p3").append($($items.get(random)).find("Respuesta#3"));

Now, in the title I put: <Title id="0" class="1">Capital de Francia</Title>

where "class" is the correct answer. How do I get the class from this xml?